# Hibernate Query with entity-name

Tags: java, hibernate, hbmxml

I am using a POJO to define two tables (Main and backup). Both XML Classes are refering to same Java Class.

Reference : [Mapping same POJO to more than one table in Hibernate XML mapping files](http://www.coderanch.com/t/492558/ORM/databases/Mapping-POJO-table-Hibernate-XML)

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mypackage.model.Table1" table="Table1" entity-name="Table1">
        <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="age" type="int">
            <column name="AGE" />
        </property>
    </class>

    <class name="com.mypackage.model.Table1" table="Table2" entity-name="Table2">
        <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="age" type="int">
            <column name="AGE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

POJO Defination:

```
public class Table1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -594654774484987124L;

    private Long id;
    private String Name;
    private int Age;
// Getters and setters.... Removed...
}
```

I am able to create to different tables. And also using

```
   session.saveOrUpdate(entityName, myObject)
```

API I am able to add new records these table individually.

While retrieving, I am using HQL

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Table1");
list = query.list();
```

It returns me all records in Table1 as well as Table2. If I tried to give Table2, then Error is showed "Table2 is not mapped"

Is there any to retrive records from ONLY table1 and Table2 individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add attribute  `polymorphism="explicit"` to u r class tag.

code :

```
 <class name="com.mypackage.model.Table1" table="Table1" entity-name="Table1" polymorphism="explicit">
```

Comment: How do I retrieve records from Table2

Comment: Got It,  Query query = session.createQuery("from Table2"); - Thanks for your help.

Comment: It even works when I can only update one mapping file. My "Table1" definition is in a library. I didn't fancy copying it into the project to change and I don't need to; making "Table2" polymorphism="explicit" was enough.